# Does the Gauss functions are denses in Schwartz?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if the Gauss function are dense in Schwartz, i.e. is the set $$\{\pm e^{-a(x-x_0)^2} \mid x_0\in \mathbb R, a>0\}$$
dense in Schwartz space ? I suspect that it's wrong, but I just want a confirmation.

Comment: Gauss functions are not dense, but linear combinations of Gauss functions are, as shown by reuns below.

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi$ is Schwartz, let $$\varphi_n(x) = \varphi \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(y)n e^{-\pi n^2 (x-y)^2}dy$$ Then $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ in the Schwartz topology.

Also $\varphi_n$ can be approximated arbitrary well in the Schwartz topology by $$\varphi_{n,K}(x) =\sum_{k=-K}^K \frac{1}{K}\varphi(\frac{k}{K}) n e^{-\pi n^2 (x-\frac{k}{K})^2}$$